# Pointing an external URL to always go to same instance of a Docker container

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-swarm, traefik

I have the following use case that I would appreciate any input on. I have a Docker Swarm running with Traefik pointed to it for ingress and routing. Currently I have it as a single service that is defined to have 6 replicas of the same image, so works out to be two containers each on three nodes.

The containers basically host a GraphQL server and my requirement is that depending on which client the request is coming from, it always goes to the same specific container (ie replica). So as an example say I have user1 and user2 at client1 and user3 and user4 at client2, if user1 makes a request and it goes to replica1, then if user2 makes a request it MUST go to replica1 as well. So basically, I could take a numeric hash on the client id (client1) and mod 6 it and decide which replica it goes to and in that way make sure any subsequent calls from any user in that client id goes to the same replica. Additionally, that information of what client the call is coming from is coded in a JWT token that the user sends in their request.

Any idea how I would go about changing my Docker Swarm to implement this? My best guess is to change the swarm to not be 6 replicas and instead define each container as a separate service with its own port. Then I could potentially point Traefik to nginx or something similar which would then receive the request, grab the JWT, decode it to find the client id, take a hash and then internally route it to the appropriate node:port combination.

But I feel like there must be a more elegant and simpler way of doing this. Maybe Traefik could facilitate this directly somehow or Docker Swarm has some configuration that I don't know about, that could be used. Any ideas?

Edit: **Just to clarify my usecase, not just looking for the same user to always go to the same container but the same type of user to always go to the same container**

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of routing you need to setup Traefik for [Sticky Sessions](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/services/)

This is a Traefik middleware that adds a cookie to responses that is used in subsequent requests to route to the same service.

Comment: Thanks, but that is not my usecase. Not just looking for the same user to always go to the same container but the same type of user to always go to the same container

Comment: Presumably the same middleware idea applies. you need some other way to feed the user type to traefik and for traefik to hash it to a container instance.